How do I close an area using Python in Blender 4.1?
I want to close a panel from within my Python addon. Existing questions and answers seem to yield results that no longer work as they are very dated. The suggested code to run is:
override_context = bpy.context.copy() 
area = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "DOPESHEET_EDITOR"][-1]     
override_context['window'] = bpy.context.window
override_context['screen'] = bpy.context.screen
override_context['area'] = area
override_context['region'] = area.regions[-1]
override_context['scene'] = bpy.context.scene

areas = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "DOPESHEET_EDITOR"]

for area in areas:
    bpy.ops.screen.area_close(override_context)

This produces an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.config/blender/4.1/scripts/addons/some_addon/__init__.py", line 67, in handle_load_post
    viewport.close_animation_area()
  File "/home/user/.config/blender/4.1/scripts/addons/some_addon/viewport.py", line 34, in close_animation_area
    bpy.ops.screen.area_close(override_context)
  File "/usr/share/blender/4.1/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 106, in __call__
    C_exec, C_undo = _BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/blender/4.1/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 60, in _parse_args
    raise ValueError("1-2 args execution context is supported")
ValueError: 1-2 args execution context is supported

